# I cannot add content to my collection when it has a relation field to another collection

Tags: javascript, api, error-handling, strapi, headless-cms

I have two collections in strapi. one of which has a relation field of type many to many that connects both of these collection.

when I try to add content to these collection I cannot. it throws error. on screen it says "something went wrong" and on browser panel it shows

```
[Error] TypeError: s.split(".").at is not a function. (In 's.split(".").at(-1)', 's.split(".").at' is undefined)
```

why is is happening?

It should've added content.

Comment: Hi, this quite small amount of info, but likely you have some sort of db error, you prolly want to drop database and start over...

Comment: Did you ever fix this?